# How perform mouseover event on pair of items in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I effectively have two columns of text that I added as shown below.

If I select all .labels and perform a mouseover function on "this", then the function will only operate on the text in the text under the mouse.

Question: How can I write an on mouseover function such that the action occurs on "this" entire row (both columns)?

I have a feeling this desired behavior will require me to enter the text differently... ???

Any guidance is appreciated.

```
//column 1
svg.selectAll("labels")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        if (xValue(d) < 0) {
            return xScale(xValue(d)) - 15;
            }
            else {
                return xScale(0) - 15;
                }
        })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d)); })
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.lineitem + " " + parseFloat(d.diff).toFixed(1); });

//column 2
svg.selectAll("labels")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .attr("x", xScale(d3.max(data, xValue)) + 50)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d)); })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return parseFloat(d.time0).toFixed(1); });
```

Comment: post your html please

Comment: Sure thing. Here it is. @Susheel-Singh
http://plnkr.co/edit/gdTkyjkoi0IHAzsaXHRG?p=catalogue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way.

```
//column 1
svg.selectAll(".labels")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("id",function(d,i){ return "column1_"+i; }) //Add a unique id with it's column name
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        if (xValue(d) < 0) {
            return xScale(xValue(d)) - 15;
            }
            else {
                return xScale(0) - 15;
                }
        })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d)); })
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.lineitem + " " + parseFloat(d.diff).toFixed(1); });

//column 2
svg.selectAll(".labels")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .attr("id",function(d,i){ return "column2_"+i; }) //Add a unique id with it's column name
    .attr("x", xScale(d3.max(data, xValue)) + 50)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d)); })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return parseFloat(d.time0).toFixed(1); });

svg.selectAll(".labels").on("mouseover,funtion(d,i){
   d3.select("#column1_"+i).style("opacity",0.2); //Perform the same action on text in column1
   d3.select("#column2_"+i).style("opacity",0.2); //Perform the same action on text in column2
});
```

Comment: I get what you're trying to do--I should have thought of that! Unfortunately, I can't get the on() to work properly. Inspecting the elements does in fact show that the IDs were added correctly.I have this:     svg.selectAll("labels")
        .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
            d3.select("column1_"+i)
                .style("opacity", .2);
            });

Comment: Sorry. my mistake. The selector should be `.labels`. Try `d3.selectAll(".labels")`. Updated the answer. Also prefix # to the id name `d3.select("#column1_"+i)`.

Comment: Yeah--i tried that too. .labels does trigger an alert() on hover, but no text changes opacity. :/ I was previously doing it with d3.select(this). Can I specify "this" along with the id?

Comment: Ahhh! we forgot the "#" too! now it works! thanks a lot! It should be: d3.select("#column1_"+i)... Thanks!